# indexOf() with for loop

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am trying to check if the first element of the array contains all letters from the second element of the array. But it doesn't work properly on this given properties. I can't find where do I do a mistake?

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var first = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var second = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  
    for(i = 0; i<second.length; i++){
     return first.indexOf(second[i]) !== -1 ? true : false;
    }


}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Comment: You always `return` after having tested the first letter. You'll want to return when you found a letter that doesn't match, or when you have checked all letters.

Comment: Yep, Bergi has your answer.  Also, I think that ternary is unnecessary, as  the result of `first.indexOf(second[i]) !== -1` will return a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition you use is not correct. You should check if all characters of the second element are contained in the the first element. So you have to check if the indexOf called on the first element for each character of the second element characters returns true. If so, then indeed all the characters of the second element are contained in the first element. Otherwise it is false.

You could try this:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
    var first = arr[0].toLowerCase();

    // we use split to get an array of the characters contained in the second element
    var second = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('');
   
    return second.every(character=>first.indexOf(character)>-1)
}

console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));
console.log(mutation(["hello", "heo"]));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both for your solution and logical help. I studied your solution. Then I learned how every() method works in ES5. And I came up with my own solution.

Comment: @emred2700 You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped.